# How to simulate cascade delete in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, lookup

I have two objects linked by a lookup. The objects are one-to-one and neither should exist without its counterpart. When one is deleted, I need the other to be deleted as well.

My plan was to put some logic in each objects' trigger. Here's what Obj 1's trigger looks like:

```
if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {
    for (Obj_1__c obj: Trigger.Old) {
        delete [select id from Obj_2__c where Obj_1__c = : obj.Id];
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the lookup is cleared out before the After Delete trigger, since the deletion of Obj 1 has already taken place. And I'm afraid using a Before Delete trigger will cause similar logic in Obj 2's trigger to create a loop, attempting to delete its Obj 1 lookup.

Is there a better way to delete records that are paired by a lookup? I know there's a built-in cascade delete, but you have to submit a ticket to SF to enable that functionality.

Comment: Which object in this scenario is the lookup field on? Or do you have a lookup field on each object that points to the other?

Comment: @JCD The lookup is on Obj_2__c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to *store the values beforehand*. Simply set up a static variable to hold the old values before deletion, then delete them after deleting:

```
public class Stash {  // Don't use statics in triggers. They behave oddly.
    public static SObject[] pendDeletes;
}

// Trigger
trigger ... on ... (before delete, after delete) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        Stash.pendDeletes = [SELECT Id FROM Obj_2__c WHERE Obj_1__c IN :Trigger.old];
    } else {
        if(Stash.pendDeletes != null) {
            SObject[] temp = Stash.pendDeletes;
            Stash.pendDeletes = null;  // Avoid recursion
            delete temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had considered this approach so I'm happy to see the suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid putting a query in a loop. Instead maybe something like this would work:

```
if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {
    List<Obj2> obj2List = new List<Obj2>();
    List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();
    for (Obj_1__c obj: Trigger.Old) {
        idList.add(obj1.lookup_to_obj2);
    }
    List<Obj2> obj2List = [SELECT Id FROM Obj2 WHERE Id IN: idList];
    if(obj2List != null){
        delete obj2List;
    }    
}
```

Comment: The query isn't the issue, so this doesn't solve anything. I understand it's not a best practice, but the objects are deleted one at a time, so I'm not concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not allow user to delete child record. Deletion of parent should delete a child record, that way you can maintain clean data.

If you can change the relationship, change it master detail OR else raise a case with Salesforce Support to activate **Cascade Delete for lookups**. Also you'll need to restrict deletion of child records so that one has to delete the parent to auto delete the child.

You won't have to write any triggers.

Comment: For a good UX with this app I need to allow the user to delete from both the parent and the child (and since these are 1-to-1 the user doesn't see it as a parent-child). Using a master-detail might be an option though. Would you happen to know if the relationship type can change for a field that's already published to a managed package?